# Population growth - population grows proportionally, increasing 2x from $t=0$ and $t=1$ and reaching 10000 at $t=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

> **Problem**: Population growth is proportional to the size of the population. From time $t=0$ to $t=1$, the population increases two times. At $t=2$, the population is $10000$. 
>   Find the population at $t=0$.

My take on it:

$P'=kP$

$P'-kP=0 \ \ | \cdot e^{-kt}$

$(Pe^{-kt})'=0$

$Pe^{-kt}=C $

$P(t)=C\cdot e^{kt}$

$P(0)=C=a $ (given notation)

$P(1)=Ce^{kt}=2a$

$C=2a\cdot e^{-k}$

$P(2)=10000=2a\cdot e^{-k}\cdot e^{2k}$

$10000=2a \cdot e^k$

Take natural logarithm on both sides,

$\ln10000=\ln(4a)\cdot k$

So this is where I have problem, I guess it's because of my lack of knowledge about logarithms. I assumed that I can take $2a$ out of $\ln$ sign as it is a constant, but then the solution is not right.

How should I do it?

Comment: $2a\cdot e^{-k}\cdot e^{2k} = 2a\cdot e^k$.

Comment: $\ln x\cdot y=\ln x+\ln y$.

Comment: @PhilH Ok, then it is even more confusing to me, what should I do? Because then $10000=4a \cdot k \Rightarrow a\cdot k = 2500$, but then how do I get rid of that k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

$$ P(t) = Ce^{kt}$$

At time 0 and 1,

$$P(0) = C, \>\>\> P(1) = C e^{k}$$

Then, take the ratio
$$ \frac{P(1)}{P(0)}= e^k=2$$

At time 2,

$$ P(2) = Ce^{2k} = P(0)e^{2k}= 10000$$

Thus, the population at time 0 is,
$$P(0) =\frac{10000}{e^{2k}}= \frac{10000}{2^2}=2500$$

Comment: @ Quanto k = ln(2) so the equation is $P(t) = 2500e^{\ln (2)t}$ which simplifies  to  $P(t) = 2500\cdot 2^t$

Comment: @Phil H - looks right and makes sense, i.e. doubling every period. Nice observation.